# mysql boolean joins

Tags: mysql, join

I want to use a JOIN to return a boolean result.  Here's an example of the data...

t1

```
id | data 
-----------
1  | abcd     
2  | 2425     
3  | xyz
```

---

t2

```
id | data | t1_id |
-------------------------
1  | 75   |     2     |    
2  | 79   |     2     |    
3  | 45   |     3     |
```

---

So with these two tables I want to select all the data from t1, and also whether a given variable appears in t2.data for each id.

So say the variable is 79, the results should be

```
id |  data  |  t2_boolean
--------------------------
1  |  abcd  |  0    
2  |  abcd  |  1    
3  |  xyz   |  0
```

---

So I'm thinking some sort of join is needed, but without a WHERE clause.
I've been banging my head about this one.  Is it possible?  I really need it inside the same statement as I want to sort results by the boolean field.

As the boolean needs to be a field, can I put a join inside of a field?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to do a bit of work to knock this into a format suitable for MySQL but does this help?

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.data, t2.id IS NOT NULL AS t2_boolean
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id AND t2.data = 79
```

Comment: Hopefully it's suitable for MySQL though!

Comment: I deleted my answer since it used the wrong join, but it's probably worth mentioning that you can just do `t2.id IS NOT NULL AS t2_boolean` instead of using a CASE

Comment: @Martin: MySQL has supported ANSI `CASE` since 5.0: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Comment: @Michael and @OMG Ponies  Thanks. I've updated mine accordingly.